# Somehow mapped "-" to escape and can't figure out how to map it back

Tags: shortcut-keys, keyboard-layout, i3-wm, xev

Really stupid question, how would I remap "-" to its default value (and to turn it into an underscore when I press it with shift).

Output of key event with `xev`:

```
KeyRelease event, serial 34, synthetic NO, window 0xc00001,
    root 0x1a8, subw 0x0, time 1776774, (-96,555), root:(3115,604),
    state 0x0, keycode 20 (keysym 0xff1b, Escape), same_screen YES,
    XKeysymToKeycode returns keycode: 9
    XLookupString gives 1 bytes: (1b) ""
    XFilterEvent returns: False
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You you're running X you can just re-apply the keyboard layout:

```
setxkbmap it
```

"it" stands for Italian in my case, you must use the code that suits your keyboard.

```
man setxkbmap
```

For more info.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, `setxkbmap -layout us` did the trick!